# Pass generic type to Theory

Tags: c#, generics, integration-testing, xunit

I've got following integration test for a repository:

```
public class RepositoryTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetAllAdressen_ReturnsEntities_OK_Test()
    {
        await GetAll_ReturnsEntities_OK_Test<AdresseEntity>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetAllApplikationsarten_ReturnsEntities_OK_Test()
    {
        await GetAll_ReturnsEntities_OK_Test<ApplikationsartEntity>();
    }

    private static async Task GetAll_ReturnsEntities_OK_Test<TEntity>()
        where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        // Arrange
        var dbContext = new SaiTestContext();
        var repository = new Repository<TEntity>(dbContext);

        // Act
        var entities = await repository.GetAllAsync();

        // Assert
        Assert.NotEmpty(entities);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to remove both `[Fact]` and convert the `private static async Task GetAll_ReturnsEntities_OK_Test<TEntity>()` into a `[Theory]` while specifying `TEntity` somehow with `InlineData`?

Comment: `Theory` passes parameters to test at runtime, generic types are resolved at compile time, how do you want to achieve it? Passing `Type` instance seems to be an ugly workaround

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thanks, it probably would but the additional effort is not worth the gain. I'll keep it as it is.